# XSD: Using Visual studio xsd.exe not generating Array[] instead of List<>

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd

Im using the xsd.exe tool to generate classes from a xsd file.
The xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  elementFormDefault="qualified"      attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="BAXML">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation></xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>      
    <xs:element name="Limit" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10">    
     <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="LimitType">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation></xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="3"/>
                <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Amount">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation></xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The output is:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class BAXML {

private string counterpartyOrgNrField;

private BAXMLLimit[] limitField;


/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Limit")]
public BAXMLLimit[] Limit {
    get {
        return this.limitField;
    }
    set {
        this.limitField = value;
    }
}}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class BAXMLLimit {

private string limitTypeField;

private int amountField;

/// <remarks/>
public string LimitType {
    get {
        return this.limitTypeField;
    }
    set {
        this.limitTypeField = value;
    }}

/// <remarks/>
public int Amount {
    get {
        return this.amountField;
    }
    set {
        this.amountField = value;
    }
}}
```

Instead of:

```
private BAXMLLimit[] limitField;
```

I would like it to be

```
List<BAXMLLimit> limitField
```

Is there a way in the xsd todo this? Or some other way?
Thx!

Comment: Maybe you could trim a bit your 'code' extracts to only show relevant information, a bit TL;DR right now.

Comment: The "some other way" is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623749/visual-studio-xsd-tool-generate-collections-rather-than-arrays).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [xsd2code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/). This works better than xsd.exe. You can also specify as an option how you want your collections to be.. List or an Array by setting the CollectionObjectType property.